# MySql in cluster environment

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing

Does MySql support for cluster environment? Whether Community edition support for clustering?

I want to know more details about it. Please guide me where can I get details?

Comment: define what sort of clustering you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You can read everything about MySQL Cluster (which is a different version than MySQL Community, but you can get both for free) on the MySQL website:
http://www.mysql.com/products/database/cluster/

MySQL Community edition can be set up to do master-slaves replication, but that's not as cool and effective as what MySQl Cluster can do.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, MySQL Cluster does support clustering. If you have a Amazon EC2 account, I recommend this tool/website for setting up a MySQL Cluster quickly for testing: http://support.severalnines.com/entries/20916823-installing-on-amazon-ec2

MySQL Cluster is apparently the only MySQL solution right now from Oracle (outside of Percona and others) that allows for 99.999% availability (HA).

From my initial tests, MySQL Cluster is really fast at writes, but slightly slower at reads, though it aggressively caches reads after the first read. I'm still studying it myself.

Also, MySQL Cluster community edition should suffice for most use cases. I think the Carrier Grade edition is only for real heavy-duty uses.

Answer (score 0):

You can get straight to the community (GPL) download for MySQL Cluster at http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/cluster/ (or the commercial version from Oracle e-Delivery - the functionality and underlying code base is the same).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to MySQL Cluster is SchoonerSQL, a cluster based on MySQL but uses the standard InnoDB storage engine rather than NDB.  It supports 99.999% availability and has a very simple GUI management console. Go to SchoonerInfoTechcom